# How to deconstruct hypothesis in Coq Proof Assistant?

Tags: logic, coq, proof

I'm trying to proof the theorem of Regular Languages in CoqIDE.

I need to deconstruct hypothesis `H1 : s1 \in "a" || "b"` into `H2 : s1 \in "a"` **without** creating additional sub-goals.

I used `inversion H2` tactic, but it created additional sub-goal. So, is it possible to deconstruct hypothesis without creating additional sub-goals?

```
3 subgoals
w : word
H : w \in ("a" || "b");; "c"
s1, s2, s3 : list ascii
H1 : s1 \in "a" || "b"
______________________________________(1/3)
w = ["a"; "c"]
```

Comment: What do you without creating other subgoals? If `s1 \in "a" || "b"` then surely it can come from `s1 in a` or `s1 in b` no? So yo would have to treat both cases.

Comment: "I need to deconstruct hypothesis H1 : s1 \in "a" || "b" into H2 : s1 \in "a" without creating additional sub-goals."  That is not possible, because s1 can be either in "a" or in "b" and you are expecting it to be in "a".